# Getting non owner to execute a job

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, permissions, sql-server-agent, jobs

I've attempted to implement solution three from the following Q & A:

[Allow non-sysadmin, non-owner of a SQL Server Agent job to execute it](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/72090/allow-non-sysadmin-non-owner-of-a-sql-server-agent-job-to-execute-it/72098#72098)

Table created and stored procedure created in `msdb`, inserted rows as needed.

When I execute the stored procedure in an SSMS query window as the non-owner of the job, it executes as expected.  However, when I put the execute command in a SQL Server job, the execution dialogue box reports successful execution, but the job did not run - as evidenced by lack of impact on the tables the job affects.

Using SQL Server 2014, a non-owner user has these permissions within msdb: SQLAgentReaderRole, stored procedure execute, is member of a db role that has db_owner permission and is named on the indicated table. This user also has ownership of the job which executes the stored procedure.

What am I missing?

Comment: What rows did you put in the table?

Comment: Did you create the stored procedure using a sysadmin account?