# Giving access to only one SQL Agent Job

Tags: sql-server, permissions, jobs

I need to allow a user only to execute a specific Agent job, rather than be able to execute the other jobs that are there . Please advise how to accomplish this.

This user will only run a copy only backup before he updates the application and I don't want to give him access to the other jobs. Ola Hallengren scripts are used for that job.

I added the user to the `DB_BackupOperator` role. If I simply make him the owner of that job will he be able to run the other jobs that are owned by SA?

Comment: If the job is to be executed manually, why use a job at all?

Answer (score 1):

It'd be easier to just `grant execute` on Ola's proc to that user. Granted, here they'd be able to call the proc with whatever parameters they want. See [Allow non-sysadmin, non-owner of a SQL Server Agent job to execute it](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/72090) if you don't want to go that route. Depending on the route you take, you may duplicate the job and make them the owner of their own job.

While `DB_BACKUPOPERATOR` would be needed, it isn't enough here. If you read that answer it explains a way, but again it'd be easier to just let them execute the procedure or use a batch script and give them permission to run the batch script. Or use [`sqlcmd`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlcmd-utility?view=sql-server-2017) which Ola's scripts support - [scsimon](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/95107/scsimon)

If you make him the owner of that one job only and add him as a member of [SQL Server Agent Fixed Database Roles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/agent/sql-server-agent-fixed-database-roles?view=sql-server-2017) `SQLAgentUserRole` should be able to execute the job. - [sqlworldwide](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/48093/sqlworldwide)